# Min, max and step for address ranges

Tags: python, pandas, range, sequence, street-address

I have a Pandas Dataframe with 16,000 addresses that are grouped together by street and city. I need to find the min, max and step between sequential ranges of address.

For example, 10,12,14,16 Main street. min is 10, max is 16 and step is 2.

The issue is the ranges are not always as simple, some are not true address ranges and are instead addresses spread along a street.

For example, 4456, 5567, 6678, main street.

I'd like to be able to identify sequential ranges and their min, max and step and separate those that are not sequential into individual rows.

Those far I have min and max figured out but I can not wrap my head around how to find sequential addresses.

```
    df['street_min']=[min(x) for x in df['Street Number'].tolist()]
    df['street_max']=[max(x) for x in df['Street Number'].tolist()]
```

sample data

```
    ID    Street_number     Street_Name
    1     [10,12,14,16]     Main St
    2     [4456, 5567, 6657] First St        (These 3 would become 3 unique records)
    3     [60,65,70, 100]   Second St         (This example would keep 60-70 and remove 100 to another row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's explode `Street_number`, find the consecutive differences and group on that along with `ID`:

```
df = df.explode('Street_number')

# consecutive differences
df['diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['Street_number'].diff().bfill()

# groups
df['group'] = df.groupby('ID')['diff'].transform(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum())

# output:
(df.groupby(['group','ID'], as_index=False)
   .agg(Street_number=('Street_number',list),
        Street_Name=('Street_Name', 'first'),
        min_number=('Street_number','min'),
        max_number=('Street_number', 'max')
       )
)
```

Output:

```
   group  ID     Street_number Street_Name  min_number  max_number
0    1.0   1  [10, 12, 14, 16]     Main St          10          16
1    1.0   2      [4456, 5567]    First St        4456        5567
2    1.0   3      [60, 65, 70]   Second St          60          70
3    2.0   2            [6657]    First St        6657        6657
4    2.0   3             [100]   Second St         100         100
```

Comment: @aguay091 not sure how the data/expected output looks like. Maybe you can try posting a new question.